# Checking if a column in GridView has bitmap

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a grid view with a few columns. the first is a checkbox, the other two are textbox and the last one is an image column.
This column contents computer names and their status, in the image column there is Bitmap image that says if the computer in Online or Offline.
I have a List that I want to add there computers only that are online and check their checkbox in the gridview.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < compGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (compGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value == Properties.Resources.Online)
                {
                    compGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = true;
                    ComputersList.Add(compGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
```

But the if not working and always exits out and saying that it's false but the image in the column is "Online"...

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What Value have the left part of condition in debug?

Comment: You can't compare images this way. Find another way to check if a computer is on/off line.

Comment: Meaby its possible to compare name of this images have You tried ? Would be much esier for You to create additional column with true/false for computer status, hide this column and use only for Your logic

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I figured out that I really cannot do a comparison with images so I went with Kuba Do recommendation and created a hidden column and relied on that.

Thanks!